# devise confirmable migration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm new to ruby on rails and am having difficulty understanding the error I'm seeing here and I can't find it when I'm searching.

I'm adding Devise to my application and would like to make it confirmable. So I added Devise to the gem file, bundle install, added line to development.rb, did the root'home#home' thing, and added the notification/alert to layout. No issues.

model/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

migration file

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      # t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      # t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      # t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      # t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
      # t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

      # Confirmable
      t.string   :confirmation_token
      t.datetime :confirmed_at
      t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Now when I run `$ rails db:migrate`

I get the error

```
== 20180816012427 DeviseCreateStudents: migrating =============================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0021s
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0013s
-- add_index(:users, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0013s
-- add_index(:users, :confirmation_token, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0016s
-- add_index(:users, :unlock_token, {:unique=>true})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table users has no column named unlock_token: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "index_users_on_unlock_token" ON "users" ("unlock_token")
```

I'm still learning what different errors mean but wasn't able to find what this means. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: The error says that in your table you don't have the column `unlock_token` but you're trying to add index to a non existing column, hence the migration error. Either uncomment the line that says `# t.string   :unlock_token` if you're going to use locking strategy or comment this line `add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true` and run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I don't understand the act of adding an index as well as I thought. I'll go over that subject again.

Answer (score 0):

The first comment is correct. I didn't understand indexing as well I thought.